# Unconditionally assign a class to an Angular component's host element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-hostbinding

I have some Angular component to which I want to **unconditionally** assign a class. This can be done using the `host` property on the `@Component` decorator:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `<!-- template -->`,
  host: {
    'class': 'my-unconditional-class'
  }
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

However, our linting rules recommend we don't:

> Use @HostBinding or @HostListener rather than the `host` metadata property (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-06-03) eslint([@angular-eslint/no-host-metadata-property](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-host-metadata-property.md))

I'm wondering how this is best done then.
It seems like the solution would be:

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `<!-- template -->`,
})
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.my-unconditional-class')
  protected readonly hostClass = true;
}
```

But that honestly seems like a lot of extra code with no obvious benefit.
You also have to name the field something "meaningful".
This especially becomes annoying when you start having multiple classes to bind.

Comment: Yeah, I would disable that rule...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not improving too much on the extra number of characters for a single class, it seems that for multiple classes on the host, it is shorter to just bind a string to `class`:

```
@HostBinding("class")
protected readonly classes = "my-many unconditional-classes for-the-host";
```

This also allows for a more generic field name like `classes`, `hostClasses` or `cssClasses`.